# Не отключается rewrite для одной папки

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite

В корне htaccess

```html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)$ ?param1=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ ?param1=$1&param2=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ ?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ ?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ ?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4&param5=$5 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ ?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4&param5=$5&param6=$6 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ ?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4&param5=$5&param6=$6&param7=$7 [QSA,L]

AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Есть папка /123/321
В ней .htaccess RewriteEngine Off

При переходе в папку /123/321 - все равно выдает 301 на /123/321/ (Добавляет слеш на конце...)

Comment: Тут нет ошибки. Это стандартное поведение apache. У вас есть реальная папка. Ссылка на реальную папку должна заканчиваться слешем. Отсюда редирект.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете добавить исключающее правило в тот файл `.htaccess`, что лежит в корне.

Вместо

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Напишите

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/123/321$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```